# NordVPN doesn't let me select country when I close and restart it. Works fine first time

Tags: windows-10, nordvpn

I've recently subscribed to and downloaded NordVPN, and it works perfectly until I close and restart it.

I am using Windows 10.

When I open it after the first time, I can only do "quick connect" and neither search for countries nor click on them on the map, the map doesn't display any locations either.

Obviously I want to be able to connect to servers in other countries.

When I uninstalled and reinstalled it, it worked again for the first time, but then when I restarted it I had the same problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you reached out to their support since this is clearly a problem with their client?